# How to select the last cell containing the same value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a datasets which contains same value.Please find the below datasets,

`Parent
Child
Child
Child
Parent
Child
Child
Parent
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child
Child`

I have count member of each parent. That means, on the 1st parent's member is 4,2nd parent's members are 3 etc.

I have written a following formula for that,

`=+IF(B6="Parent",COUNTA(B6:B9)," ")`

when i drag entire formula, on the count section, it will automatically fetch the next parent's row number, but each time i have to change the row number of child part.

How can i select the last child's row number so that, each time i don't have to change?
is there any way to do more efficient of above formula?

any suggestion is really appreciable.

Comment: From where your data starts? Where you putting formula? How you want output? Can you figure your output manually so that we can understand.

Comment: @harun24hr, the data starts from B6, i am putting the formula on A6. The expected output will be-- for the first parent's the member will be 4, 2nd parent's member will be 3 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check this one. Put the formula in `A6` then drag and down

```
=IFERROR(IF(B6="Parent",INDEX(MATCH("Parent",B7:B$23,0),1),""),COUNTA(B7:B$23)+1)
```

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Comment: @harunhr, your formula works. Thank you very much for your answer. can you please tell me why you have used index match?

Comment: If you found the formula working then you should accept (Tick as green) my answer so that other visitor can understand my answer solve your problem.

Comment: Actually you can omit `INDEX()` function so formula can shortened to `=IFERROR(IF(B6="Parent",MATCH("Parent",B7:B$23,0),""),COUNTA(B7:B$23)+1)` So, what match doing here, it is finding next `Parent` matching numer. When no `Parent` found then it is giving error. When error comes then `IFERROR()` function is handling these and counting total number of child rest adding 1 giving your desired result. See [MATCH()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php), how it works.

Comment: yeap got it fully. Thanks once again for this beautiful answer.

Comment: Glad to know it helps you.